# How to convert a list of tuples to a dictionary of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples like:

```
[(1, 'a', 22), (2, 'b', 56), (1, 'b', 34), (2, 'c', 78), (3, 'd', 47)]
```

and I need to convert it to:

```
{1: {'a': 22, 'b': 34}, 2: {'b': 56, 'c': 78}, 3: {'d': 47}}
```

Is that possible in Python? Thanks!

Comment: You can try `defaultdict`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [(1, 'a', 22), (2, 'b', 56), (1, 'b', 34), (2, 'c', 78), (3, 'd', 47)]

d = defaultdict(dict)
for x, y, z in l:
    d[x][y] = z
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`setdefault` is your friend:

```
d = {}
for t in l:
    d.setdefault(t[0],{})[t[1]]=t[2]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it in one (rather long) line, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), but remember that the list has to be `sorted` by the key for this to work:

```
>>> lst = [(1, 'a', 22), (2, 'b', 56), (1, 'b', 34), (2, 'c', 78), (3, 'd', 47)]
>>> {key: {v[1]: v[2] for v in vals} for key, vals in itertools.groupby(sorted(lst), key=operator.itemgetter(0))}
{1: {'a': 22, 'b': 34}, 2: {'b': 56, 'c': 78}, 3: {'d': 47}}
```

Comment: Fun fact: `{v[1]: v[2] for v in vals}` is exactly as long as `dict(zip(*zip(*vals)[1:]))` (but probably much more performant and readable :D )